# Laravel Eloquent load Data and related Data?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

im trying to get all available properties and their contents, if there any, by item.
I dont know exactly how to describe it..

One Item belongs to a group.
One Group can have multiple categories.
One Category can belong to multiple groups and can have multiple properties.
One Property has one category
One PropContent belongs to one item and property.

How do i get all properties available for a category with potential prop_contents by item ?

Table example:

| items | groups | categories | group_categories | item_prop_contents | category_props |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id | group_id | id | id |
| name | name | name | category_id | category_prop_id | category_id |
| group_id |  |  |  | item_id | name |
|  |  |  |  | content | type (text,bool,int) |

```
class Item extends Model
{
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Group::class);
    }

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemPropertyContent::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Group extends Model
{
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Category::class, 'group_categories');
    }

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class);
    }
}
```

```
class Category extends Model
{
    public function groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }

    public function properties()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(CategoryProperty::class);
    }
}
```

```
class CategoryProperty extends Model
{
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ItemPropertyContent::class);
    }
}
```

```
class ItemPropertyContent extends Model
{
    public function property()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(CategoryProperty::class);
    }

    public function item()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Item::class);
    }
}
```

I know it is maybe not perfectly explained, but i dont know how to name it.

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For everyone comming around, this is my solution:

```
        $item->load(['group.categories.properties.content' => function ($query) use ($item) {
            $query->where('item_id', '=', $item->id);
        }]);
```